# Uncaught Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty

Tags: mongodb, meteor, simple-schema

everyone. I am working on an attendance system using meteor.js. So I have two collections `subject` , `student`. In this system, a form will be submitted with selected studentID and subjectCode for subject enrollment. However, I got this error when I submitted. `Uncaught Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty.`

The subject schema is like this

```
const subjectSchema = new SimpleSchema({
subjectCode:{
type: String,
label: “Subject Code”,
index:true,
unique:true
},
subjectName:{
type: String,
label: “Subject Name”,
index:true,
unique:true
},
enrollment:{
type: Array,
optional: true
},
‘enrollment.$’:String,
});
```

For actions

```
Template.enroll.events({
  'submit form':function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(e.target).find('[name=studentID]').val();
    var subjectCode = $(e.target).find('[name=subjectCode]').val();

    subject.update(
      {subjectCode:subjectCode},
      {$push:{"enrollment.$":name}});
  }
});
```

If anyone could help me out here I would really appreciate it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you confirm that `name` is not `undefined`?

Comment: @Jankapunkt name is defined in another schema. And both variables can renturn values from console.log().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here [Meteor Forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/uncaught-error-after-filtering-out-keys-not-in-the-schema-your-modifier-is-now-empty/52245/3).

Code should be like this:

```
subject.update(
      {subjectCode:subjectCode},
      {$addToSet:{"enrollment":name}});
  }
```